# windows registry to manage Enable pointer shadow

Tags: windows, mouse, windows-registry, regedit

I have being doing some research on Google but I cannot find what is the windows registry to manage Enable pointer shadow. I need to find it to do a global update for my citrix gold image.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Take a look](http://virtualfeller.com/2010/08/03/optimize-windows-7-visual-effects-for-virtual-desktops/):

This is done by creating a user-based GPO that sets the following registry key:

```
Key: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects
Value Name: VisualFXSetting
Value Type: dword
Value data: 3
```

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is only partially correct.

The `VisualFXSetting` value controls only how the settings are determined, as indicated on the `System Properties\Advanced system settings\Advanced tab\Performance Options` dialog:

```
0 = Let Windows choose what's best for my computer
1 = Adjust for best appearance
2 = Adjust for best performance
3 = Custom
```

In our case, of course, we want to use 3.

Once we've selected 3, our job gets harder. The data controlling the settings themselves is a little more complex, involving hexadecimal entries (bytes) set at this registry value:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\UserPreferencesMask
```

For our purposes here we're interested only in the first three bytes, i.e.:

```
9E 3E 07
```

The bytes are determined by conversion from these binary sets:

```
10011110 00111110 00000111
```

(We can use Windows Calculator for the conversions; we'll press Alt+3 for the Programmer view and choose Word as our word size.)

The binary sets are calculated from these templates:

```
    ^^^    ^ ^^        ^
1001ABC0 00D1EF10 00000G11
```

The letters represent entries from this list:

```
A - Smooth-scroll list boxes
B - Slide open combo boxes
C - Fade or slide menus into view 
D - Show shadows under mouse pointer 
E - Fade or slide ToolTips into view 
F - Fade out menu items after clicking 
G - Show shadows under windows
```

So, for example, if we wanted to turn off everything except `Smooth-scroll list boxes` we'd set the 5th bit (bit 4 on a zero-based list) of the 1st set to 1:

```
    ^
10011000 00010010 00000011
```

And then use Windows Calculator to convert it to hexadecimal:

```
98 12 03
```

Everything on:

```
10011110 00111110 00000111 = 9E 3E 07
```

Everything off:

```
10010000 00010010 00000011 = 90 12 03
```

Comment: **UserPreferencesMask**  see here

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957204.aspx
and https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/3d2472d6-973b-4125-ba7e-41602aa3b51b/script-to-enable-cursor-shadow?forum=ITCG